# OSError Err 22 [Invalid Argument] when scraping NASA website using python script

Tags: web-scraping, python-3.7

I've just put together a little scraping script within my Windows environment in order to download all pictures from the associated url's within the main index url. A few pictures download into the subdirectory but the code dumps out with the error:

> "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
>   'apod_pictures\start?type=1x1'"

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Alun.

```
import os
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Download index page

base_url = "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html"
download_directory = "apod_pictures"
content = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url).read()

# For each link on the index page
for link in BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml").findAll("a"):
    print("Following link:", link)
    href = urljoin(base_url, link["href"])
# follow the link and pull down the image held on that page

    content = urllib.request.urlopen(href).read()
    for img in BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml").findAll("img"):
        img_href = urljoin(href, img["src"])
        print("Downloading image:", img_href)
        img_name = img_href.split("/")[-1]
        "".join(x for x in img_name if x.isalnum())
        "".join(x for x in download_directory if x.isalnum())
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_href, `os.path.join(download_directory, img_name))`


"OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'apod_pictures\\start?type=1x1'"
```

When I first saw the issue, I tried inserting the lines of code seen above and below, which didn't seem to correct things:

```
    "".join(x for x in img_name if x.isalnum())
    "".join(x for x in download_directory if x.isalnum())
```